# Where is Spring-MVC 4.3.3 ? I dont find them in the Spring projects page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

I am unable to find the Spring-MVC project under spring.io/projects.
Its not available in docs/reference as well.
But able to locate the same under their repo "http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/"

Comment: Spring MVC is not a separate project but a module under the base framework. See [the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) for the list of modules in the framework.

Comment: I doubt it. The documentation simply explains the webmvc framework. The classes related to webmvc are not with base spring-framework. Just adding spring-webmvc to maven, still works as usual. I just wonder, then why its removed from the projects page

Comment: Being distributed as a separate JAR does not mean that it is not part of the base framework. See the section in the official documentation on [naming convention](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#dependency-management) to see the current a list of JARs in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the spring-webmvc project, it's at the bottom of the page:

[image]

Comment: I am able to find it from the repository. My question was, why it was removed from the spring.io projects page

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the API for somewhat later Spring 4.3.16](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.16.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/package-summary.html) both Spring Web, as well as Spring Test for example, are full citizens of the Spring Framework itself. As is true in Spring 4.3.3. Just activate Frames to move around in the class hierarchy.

I know multiple replies already gave this information, but I think looking in to the Javadoc-API makes this more clear.